# Re-applying after visit visa refusal in Canada

Tags: canada

I am currently employed by a company in Canada and work in the Middle East for them. I had to be there on 6th October 2017 for some orientation and training. I applied for a visit visa around the end of September with the invitation letters provided by my employer. This was obviously too tight, in hope that I would get the visa quickly.

I got the refusal today (25th October) with the official reason being

> You have not satisfied me that you would leave Canada at the end of your stay as a temporary resident. In reaching this decision, I considered several factors, including: Having a legitimate business purpose in Canada

I am assuming this is because 6th October has already passed.

Anyway, how can I apply again? I have new invitation letters, this time for December.

Shall I start a new application?

Is there some way to just resupply these new invitation letters?

Comment: I'm not a visa expert, but you should probably assume that the refusal was for the stated reason, and not because it was last-minute. They say they think your application is bogus and you intend to overstay.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany hmm in that case i am not sure how i am going to satisfy them. I do have an extensive travel history in Europe and also have a valid B2 US Visa.

Comment: I think you should speak with your company. It is your company problem, and I think the company did something wrong. (timing, invitation, but also documenting paid flight and accommodation, reason of travel, etc.)

Comment: @HaniQ: did you documented your travel history (and your US visa)? That could help (lower probability of overstay)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yeah i did. Providing details in the Travel History section. Based on all this i am assessing that the reason can be purely the date of my purpose of visit being expired, Yeah i am going to reapply with new Invitation, Bookings, etc. But wanted to know. Looking at the Application portal. It seems i need to create a new application. It will be a new process all over again. Arent my chances much better if i challenge this refusal and provide the new invitation etc somehow ? can that be done ?

Comment: What nationality or passport do you have?

Comment: Please upload a full scan of your refusal letter. Thank you.